# Javascript array to string manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have an array like this:

```
testData=["Telephone","Wifi","Mobile","Fax"]
```

I want to generate a string like:

```
result=Telephone-Wifi-Mobile-Fax
```

from this array.

How can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't the `Array.prototype.join()` method do what you want?

Comment: How do I replace , by -   ?

Comment: The separator is the argument to the method.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var testData= ["Telephone","Wifi","Mobile","Fax"]
var result = testData.join('-');
document.write(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
let testData=["Telephone","Wifi","Mobile","Fax"]

let str = testData.join(',').replaceAll(',', '-')
console.log(str)
```

Comment: You can pass a "-" character to `join()` instead of passing a comma and replacing it afterwards.

Comment: Why would you do that when `Array.prototype.join()` accepts the seperator as an argument?

Comment: `testData.join('-')` would suffice.. not sure why you're inserting a character you don't want and then replacing it

Answer (score 1):

as noted in the comments - you want to use .join() - but you will need the '-' chacter to join the array items

```js
const testData=["Telephone","Wifi","Mobile","Fax"]

const result = 'result='+ testData.join('-');

console.log(result);// gives result=Telephone-Wifi-Mobile-Fax
```

Comment: thanks @BSdoukos - small typo - fixed now :)

Comment: This is the only answer that read the question properly and added `result=` to the result string